# _webpack_require return an empty module object

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack 1.13.3.

_webpack_require return an empty module object.
expected result is 'a.js' module object..

source code:

a.js

```
require.ensure([], function() {

  var module = {};

  module.init = function() {
    console.log('a');
  };

  return module;
})
```

entry.js

```
require([], function() {
  console.log(require('./a'))
  require('./a').init();
})
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./main.js">
</script>
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

build with webpack.config.js and open index.html with browser.
then error appears.

console.log(require('./a')) this code logging just empty object '{}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use AMD modules with webpack, but you're far better off just using the CommonJS module style. It's what webpack was built for, is very simple and works beautifully!

Try the following instead:

a.js

```
module.exports = {}; // module.exports is what will be returned if you require() this file.

module.exports.init = function() {
  console.log('a');
}

// OR

module.exports = {
  init: function() { 
    console.log('a');
  },
};
```

entry.js

```
require('./a').init();
```

Your webpack config and HTML do not need changes.

As you can see, far simpler! Webpack will automatically wrap those modules with a function, nothing is leaked globally.

Comment: actually, my legacy code uses AMD. so I used AMD style. but thx!

Comment: @mJane, in webpack you can use AMD as a replacement for requires, but there is no way to export variables with AMD.